# How to run a query on different schemes at once

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to run a query on different schemes to get data and export it. I use the following code

```
DECLARE
  sql_statment VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN
  FOR c IN (SELECT brchcode FROM brchs) LOOP
    sql_statment := 'select distinct ''' || c.brchcode ||''', t.risuid from ' || c.brchcode ||
                    '.reg_individualacnt_detail t
                      where t.historytypecode = 60';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_statment;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

where brchcode is the name of different schemes

I can't see any output. what can I do?

Comment: Do you get errors? I think you should...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Code you wrote can't work as you have to return the result into *something*; it is PL/SQL and requires an INTO clause. As you chose to return two values (columns) and multiple rows, that can't be a scalar variable; you could pick ref cursor or a collection, for example.

Here's an example which shows one option.

I'll be using two schemas: SCOTT (current schema) and HR. Both will be having the DEPT table.

As Scott already has it, I'll create one in HR schema and grant access to Scott (otherwise, Scott won't even see it and the procedure (i.e. the *function*) will fail):

```
SQL> connect hr/hr
Connected.
SQL> create table dept (deptno number, dname varchar2(10), loc varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> insert into dept values (55, 'IT', 'Zagreb');

1 row created.

SQL> grant select on dept to scott;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.
```

Back to Scott, to create a table (which contains schema names I'll be selecting from) and a function. I chose to return REF CURSOR; you could return something else, if you want.

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger
Connected.
SQL> create table brchs (brchcode varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> insert into brchs (brchcode)
  2    select 'scott' from dual union all
  3    select 'hr'    from dual;

2 rows created.
SQL> create or replace function f_br
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    l_str varchar2(4000);
  5    l_rc  sys_refcursor;
  6  begin
  7    for cur_r in (select brchcode from brchs) loop
  8      l_str := l_str ||
  9        'union all
 10         select ' || chr(39)|| cur_r.brchcode ||chr(39) || ', d.dname
 11         from ' || cur_r.brchcode ||'.dept d
 12         where d.deptno > 0';
 13    end loop;
 14
 15    l_str := ltrim(l_str, 'union all');
 16
 17    open l_rc for l_str;
 18    return l_rc;
 19  end;
 20  /

Function created.

SQL>
```

Finally, testing:

```
SQL> select f_br from dual;

F_BR
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

'SCOT DNAME
----- --------------
scott ACCOUNTING
scott RESEARCH
scott SALES
scott OPERATIONS
hr    IT


SQL>
```

Comment: It is our capital, @Barbaros, but I don't live there. I'm 100 km north, close to Hungarian border.